Empty Transformations published by Ackermann gazebo plugin (Ros2 Humble, Gazebo Classic)
I was following the Nav2 tutorial for setting up a robot which works as expected for a diff drive (the white front wheels are due to diffdrive not publishing transformation for these, that's ok):

Then, i replaced the diffdrive plugin for my use case with the ackermann plugin, however, all transformations are empty and the wheels/links all collapse to the base_link:

Using my URDF and with the joint_state_publisher_gui without Gazebo works as expected:

The plugin is set up as specified in its docs:
    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_ackermann_drive" filename="libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive.so">
        <ros>
          <namespace>/demo</namespace>
          <!-- <remapping>cmd_vel:=cmd_demo</remapping> -->
          <!-- <remapping>odom:=odom_demo</remapping> -->
          <!-- <remapping>distance:=distance_demo</remapping> -->
          <!-- <parameter name="cmd_vel_topic" value="cmd_demo"/> -->
          <!-- <parameter name="odom_topic" value="odom_demo"/> -->
          <!-- <parameter name="distance_topic" value="distance_demo"/> -->
        </ros>
        <update_rate>100.0</update_rate>

        <!-- wheels -->
        <front_left_joint>front_left_wheel_joint</front_left_joint>
        <front_right_joint>front_right_wheel_joint</front_right_joint>
        <rear_left_joint>rear_left_wheel_joint</rear_left_joint>
        <rear_right_joint>rear_right_wheel_joint</rear_right_joint>
        <left_steering_joint>front_left_steer_joint</left_steering_joint>
        <right_steering_joint>front_right_steer_joint</right_steering_joint>
        <steering_wheel_joint>steering_joint</steering_wheel_joint>

        <!-- Max absolute steer angle for tyre in radians-->
        <!-- Any cmd_vel angular z greater than this would be capped -->
        <max_steer>0.6458</max_steer>

        <!-- Max absolute steering angle of steering wheel -->
        <max_steering_angle>7.85</max_steering_angle>

        <!-- Max absolute linear speed in m/s -->
        <max_speed>20</max_speed>

        <!-- PID tuning -->
        <left_steering_pid_gain>1500 0 1</left_steering_pid_gain>
        <left_steering_i_range>0 0</left_steering_i_range>
        <right_steering_pid_gain>1500 0 1</right_steering_pid_gain>
        <right_steering_i_range>0 0</right_steering_i_range>
        <linear_velocity_pid_gain>1000 0 1</linear_velocity_pid_gain>
        <linear_velocity_i_range>0 0</linear_velocity_i_range>

        <!-- output -->
        <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
        <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
        <publish_distance>true</publish_distance>

        <!-- disable tf -->
        <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>


        <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
        <robot_base_frame>base_link</robot_base_frame>
      </plugin>
    </gazebo>

If someone has a suggestion why diffdrive works as expected and ackermann does not, i would highly appreciate some pointers, i already excluded the STL bug in the ackermann plugin.

I updated all inertias, collision model and made them reasonble in magnitude, that helped

What do you mean by reasonable? Any examples or exact figures?

Sorry, I am unable to reproduce what exactly caused this but I saw some NaN entries
